# Freeswitch API command problems

Tags: freeswitch

I have two problems with Freeswitch v 1.6 API https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_conference#mod_conference-APIReference:

1) vid-mute-img command called as "/webapi/conference?957 vid-mute-img all /var/lib/freeswitch/images/myprepa-mute.png" and file placed to the correct location, but result always the same "/var/lib/freeswitch/images/default-mute.png" and default image is used.

2) vid-banner command called as "/webapi/conference?957 vid-banner all BannerText", but result always the same "Channel %s is not in a video layer"

What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to be clear..

Are you saying, when you call..

    /webapi/conference?957 vid-mute-img all /var/lib/freeswitch/images/myprepa-mute.png

the image used is always /var/lib/freeswitch/images/default-mute.png

?

Comment: Yes, always default image

Comment: Did you ever found a solution for this? I'm having the same issue, the vid-mute-img commands always echoes the path I send. But then FS always shows the default image.

Comment: No, sorry... We refused to use those commands